# Use an integer function to construct a sequence of discrete random variables with linearly increasing variances

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $ H $ be a positive integer function on the lower triangular part of the non-negative integer lattice, i.e.

$ H: \left \{ (n,k) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : n \geq k \geq 0 \right  \} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{>0} $, with the following properties:

1. $ H(n,k) = H(n,n-k) $ and
2. $ H(n,0) \leq H(n,1) \leq \cdots \leq H(n, \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor ) $

for all $ n \geq k \geq 0 $. In other words, $ H(n, \cdot) $ is symmetric about $ \frac{n}{2} $, increasing on $ 0 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{2} $ and decreasing on $ \frac{n}{2} \leq k \leq n $.

Now, we can use $H$ to construct a sequence of discrete random variables $X_n$ with the probability mass functions

$ p_n(k) = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{ H(n,k) }{ \sum^n_{i=0} H(n,i) } & \text{if } k \text{ is an integer that } 0 \leq k \leq n \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right. $

Obviously, $ \mathbf{E} [X_n] = \frac{n}{2} $. The question is:

> What sufficient and necessary conditions should be imposed on $H$ so
>   that $ \mathbf{Var} [X_n] \propto n $?
>
> In other words, we want a positive constant $ c > 0 $ such that
>   $ \mathbf{Var} [X_n] = cn $ for all integers $ n \geq 0 $. What kinds
>   of conditions does the existence of $c$ impose on $H$?

An example would be the sequence of symmetric binomial distributions $ H(n,k) = \binom{n}{k} $, in which $ \mathbf{Var} [X_n] = \frac{n}{4} $

Comment: What kinds of conditions are you talking about?  What kinds of pathologies are you trying to avoid?  More basically, it seems like you have some kind of application or agenda in mind, for which this question is relevant, but without knowing the background, your question looks peculiar.  Is there anything _wrong_ with your symmetric binomial example?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the symmetric binomial example. I'm just curious what kind of shape and growth we would expect on H. In the symmetric binomial example, H exhibits factorial order of growth in n and yet still manages to give "only" linearly increasing variance. The reason seems to be that H decays rapidly enough as k moves away from n/2 to counter the effect of the rapid growth in n. This suggests some kind of relation between the growth of H in n and the shape of H(n,·) for fixed n

Comment: If you make $H(1,n)=H(n,n)=1$ and $H(n,n/2)=n$ you will, I think, get your asymptotics right.  You might consider instead the problem of identifying probability measures $\eta$ on $[0,1]$ with expectation $1/2$ and variance $\ge c$ for some positive $c$; your $H$ is a kind of diophantine approximation of $\eta$.